# Python get value from index of list

Tags: python, list, indexing

Let's say I have a dict with the keys `1, 2, 3, 4` and the values are lists, e.g.:

```
{1: ['myMoney is 335', 'jeff', 'Manchester'],
 2: ['myMoney is 420', 'jeff', 'Birmingham']}
```

I want to create a function which is taking ONLY the value from the first index in the list of every key and making a sum of them. Is there any possibility to "filter" only the value out of this index for every key?

Comment: Please give us a correct `d = ...` line so we don't have to guess what you might mean. Right now it's just full of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting it is more stable if the string `'myMoney is '` changes later:

```
 d = {1: ['myMoney is 335', 'jeff', 'Manchester'], 
      2:['myMoney is 420', 'jeff', 'Birmingham']}
sum(float(value[0].split()[-1]) for value in d.values())
```

`d.values()` gives you all the values. No need for the keys here. 
`'myMoney is 335’.split()` splits the string at white spaces. We take the
last entry, i.e. the number, with the index `-1`. 
`float()` converts a string into a number.
Finally, `sum()` gives you the sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first value in your list of every key, you'd just need to do something like:

```
d[key][list_index]
```

So a function would look like:

```
d = {1: ["myMoney is 335", "Jeff", "Manchester"], 2: ["myMoney is 420", "Jeff", "Birmingham"]}

def firstValueSum(d):
    sum = 0
    for item in d:
        sum += int(d[item][0][11:])
    return sum

print firstValueSum(d)
```

Comment: yeah thats pretty sweet how you would do it, but you cant just remove the string "myMones is"....so my problem is i have the String "myMoney is 335" in the first index of the list AND i want only the value to get out of this index!

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood you a bit there. In that case you can use string slicing to ignore the first 11 characters (myMoney is) from each index. See my edited answer above :-)

Comment: oh wow nice thank you for your help!! helped me a lot, i hope so :)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1: ['myMoney is 335', 'jeff', 'Manchester'], 2:['myMoney is 420', 'jeff', 'Birmingham']}

def get_filtered(d):
    if not d:
        return {}
    return {k: int(v[0][len("myMoney is "):])
            for k,v in d.iteritems()}

assert get_filtered(d) == {1: 335, 2: 420}
summed_up = sum(get_filtered(d).itervalues())
assert summed_up == 755
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1: ["myMoney is 335", "Jeff", "Manchester"], 2: ["myMoney is 420", "Jeff", "Birmingham"]}

sum(float(v[0][11:]) for v in d.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rsplit the first string once on whitespace and get the second element  casting to int and sum:

```
print(sum(int(val[0].rsplit(None,1)[1]) for val in d.itervalues()))
```

A better approach might be to have a dict of dicts and access the item you want by key:

```
d = {1: {"myMoney":335, "name":"jeff","city":"Manchester"}, 2:{"myMoney":420, "name":"jeff", "city":"Birmingham"}}

print(sum(dct["myMoney"] for dct in d.itervalues()))
755
```